# R: creating a function which prints the line number at which it is executed

Tags: r

I'm having issues debugging some code in R ... And so I thought it might be good practice for me to put in print statements in the code to see which function is running before an error occurs. And so I thought an even nicer feature would be to include in the print statement the line that is currently being executed. Here is an example of function that I am thinking of:

```
custom_print <-  function(output_str){
     line_number <- line_number_function()
     print(paste0(line_number, " - ", output_str))
}
```

> Then I could just use `custom_print("Function A running")` in my
>   code. How can I achieve this? I am looking for a
>   `line_number_function()` which returns the line number (when the
>   code is interpreted !).

### EDIT (more details):

Here is a specific example of how I would use this

```
# test.R

# At the beginning of the R script I have this:
custom_print <-  function(output_str){
     line_number <- line_number_function()
     print(paste0(line_number, " - ", output_str))
}

# ... some code here ...

# example function
# NOTE: assume this is line 42 in my code 
add_stuff <-  function(x, y){
     custom_print("Hey I'm adding !")
     return(x+y)
}

# use my adding function
add_stuff(1, 1)
```

To be super specific, I would run this from the console in Rstudio server using:

```
system('Rscript test.R')
```

which I believe is the same as running it from the Unix/Linux command line. Then I would expect some output like this:

```
[1] 44 - Hey I'm adding !
```

The 44 here is the line in the function of the interpreted code.

Comment: Are you `source()`ing the input file? Line numbers are only available in certain specific situations. It would be nice if you provided a reproducible example showing how you would call this function and exactly what output you would expect to see from that sample input.

Comment: One problem you'll run into is that functions in R do not always wrap and/or contain comments the same as in your source file, so line numbers that R "knows" in real-time are not always the same as what are in the file itself. I'm curious to see if somebody has a better explanation, as I can certainly see value in this. Lacking that, one habit I've done in similar situations as yours is to ensure each message (via some logging function) includes something unique, typically hard-coded number or unique message.

Comment: @r2evans: thanks, I was thinking of putting in unique messages as well. That would definitely do the job. Let see if someone comes up with a solution for the line number.

Comment: It might be more useful to gain some understanding of RStudio's debugging features - [introduction here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200713843?version=1.1.463&mode=desktop).

Comment: @neilfws, assuming RStudio, that is ... (I wonder if there's any correlation between R users who don't use RStudio and those who ask questions on StackOverflow ...)

Comment: @r2evans true :) they mention Rstudio server in the question so I assumed they use it

Comment: I use RStudio Connect but don't use the RStudio IDE (often). Then again, I'm a bit of a misfit in that regards ...